# Browser.wait() fails when used in build pipeline, but works fine in local machine

Tags: typescript, azure, jasmine, protractor, azure-devops

I'm using Azure DevOps for running my Protractor test cases in a build machine. Previously all code was working fine, but it suddenly started failing on the build machine with no hint at all. The test case fails when browser.wait is called in an E2E test case.

I also verified that the local machine browser and build agent browser versions are same. The code executes in my local machine without any error.

Login page code

login.po.ts:

```
login() {
browser.wait(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(element(by.id('xxx'))), 9000);
element(by.id('xxx')).sendKeys("test");
}
```

Run.spec.ts:

```
it block for Protractor where login code is called
    it("Should display title ", () => {
        loginpage.login();
});
```

I'm running code using ng E2E.
Yarn version is 1.15.2 locally as well as build agent.
Node version  is 10.14.1 locally as well as build agent.
Chrome version 73.0.3683.86

Error message on build agent:

````
none 
at D:\BA0\10\s\src\client\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:668:7
[06:08:00] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 199
An unexpected error occurred: undefined
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
##[error]Error: The process 'D:\BA0\_tool\yarn\1.15.2\x64\yarn-v1.15.2\bin\yarn.cmd' failed with exit code 1
```
[06:03:19] E/launcher - timeout: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 10.000
  (Session info: chrome=73.0.3683.103)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.46.628402 (536cd7adbad73a3783fdc2cab92ab2ba7ec361e1),platform=Windows NT 10.0.14393 x86_64)
[06:03:19] E/launcher - TimeoutError: timeout: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 10.000
  (Session info: chrome=73.0.3683.103)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.46.628402 (536cd7adbad73a3783fdc2cab92ab2ba7ec361e1),platform=Windows NT 10.0.14393 x86_64)
    at Object.checkLegacyResponse (D:\BA0\10\s\src\client\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\error.js:546:15)
    at parseHttpResponse (D:\BA0\10\s\src\client\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\http.js:509:13)
    at doSend.then.response (D:\BA0\10\s\src\client\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\http.js:441:30)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
From: Task: WebDriver.takeScreenshot()
    at Driver.schedule (D:\BA0\10\s\src\client\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver.js:807:17)
    at Driver.takeScreenshot (D:\BA0\10\s\src\client\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver.js:1085:17)
    at run (D:\BA0\10\s\src\client\node_modules\protractor\built\browser.js:59:33)
    at ProtractorBrowser.to.(anonymous function) [as takeScreenshot] (D:\BA0\10\s\src\client\node_modules\protractor\built\browser.js:67:16)
    at D:\BA0\10\s\src\client\e2e\protractor.conf.js:96:33
    at ManagedPromise.invokeCallback_ (D:\BA0\10\s\src\client\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:1376:14)
    at TaskQueue.execute_ (D:\BA0\10\s\src\client\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:3084:14)
    at TaskQueue.executeNext_ (D:\BA0\10\s\src\client\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:3067:27)
    at asyncRun (D:\BA0\10\s\src\client\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:2927:27)
    at D:\BA0\10\s\src\client\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:668:7
[06:03:19] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 199
````

Expected on build agent: Executed successfully

Comment: Good thing that error message is super helpful. I hate it for you. This one is probably going to be painful. Good luck!

Comment: Could you share your `config` file

Comment: Is this running inside a docker image in the pipeline, or any other sort of container?

Comment: I am not aware what is docker image, but when I am connecting to the build agent I am not able to see the chrome launch

Comment: protractor = require("./protractor.conf");
var configbase = protractor.config;
var path = require('path');
var downloadsPath = path.resolve(__dirname, 'downloads');

configbase.capabilities.browserName = "chrome";
configbase.capabilities.chromeOptions = {
     args: ['--disable-gpu', '--disable-browser-side-navigation','--no-sandbox'],
};
configbase.directconnect = true;
exports.config = configbase;

Comment: check browser size at both places, Maybe taking a screenshot can help you.